# Graph Edges intialization between nodes using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, edges

Let's say I have to initialise the bi-directional edges for the following graph between the nodes:

[image]

I can easily do this using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
node_num = 3
graph = np.ones([node_num, node_num]) - np.eye(node_num)
```

Now I am extending this graph in the following way:

[image]

What is the simple and efficient way to make it code for this graph?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for an adjacency matrix, you could use:

```
out = np.block([
    [1 - np.eye(3), np.eye(3)       ],
    [    np.eye(3), np.zeros((3, 3))]
]).astype(int)
```

out:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],   # A
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],   # B
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],   # C
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # BC
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # AB
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])  # AB(red)
```

but I would suggest you just initialize it as the outputted adjacency matrix. I would only use a short one liner for very simple graphs like your first image, not the second.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Would you please share a bit more detail about outputted adjacency matrix.

Comment: Hi, in 5 nodes cases `(A, B, C, D, E, AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE)` it cannot work.

Comment: I believe this solution is just for 3 nodes case,  it will not work for `n` nodes.

Comment: waiting for your response.

Comment: How would the graph generalize for `n` nodes? A central graph fully connected graph with `n / 2` nodes, each of which has one more node connected to itself but not anywhere else?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293289/adjacency-matrix-using-numpy/75299491#75299491